# Reference Js file from TypeScript file with webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, pdf.js

I'm a bit lost... I'm trying to use PDFJS to render a PDF with JavaScript and now I need to use a plugin to make text selectable. According to [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/custom-pdf-rendering/), I have to use [this file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/v1.4.20/web/text_layer_builder.js). As it seems not to be available on npm, I added it to my source code and bundle it with webpack in a vendor.bundle.js file:

```
entry: {
    "app": "./src/index.ts",
    "vendor": ["pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry", "./vendors/uiMask.js", "./vendors/pdfjs/text_layer_builder.js"]
}
```

Now, I'd like to use it in my TypeScript file, so I do:

```
var TextLayerBuilder = require('../../../vendors/pdfjs/text_layer_builder');
```

Webpack does not complain but when I do:

```
let textLayer: any = new TextLayerBuilder({
    textLayerDiv: textLayerDiv,
    pageIndex: page.pageIndex,
    viewport: viewport
});
```

Chrome says that `TextLayerBuilder` is not a constructor. When I do a `console.log` of this object, it appears to be an empty object.

How can I use this file in my TypeScript one?

Comment: Are you sure that you do not want to use `.renderTextLayer` ?